# Android Maps v2, slow initialization

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use a map view with an expandable list view. I can successfully add the maps to the list view but the problem I'm having is that when the user firsts clicks an entry to expand, it's very slow to load because the map object has to be created. Is there someway I can either speed the loading, thread the loading or create the map object when the app is first loading? Code is below:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)  MainActivity.getInstance().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Map");

    mapFragment.onResume();

    return v;

}
```